# Installing xgboost to AWS EC2 Linux instance

Tags: gcc, amazon-ec2, cmake, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, xgboost

I have a django project which it's been deployed to Elastic Beanstalk and i have to use xgboost in that. I cannot install xgboost via adding it to my requirements.txt file. I'm trying to build it on EC2 console. For this, I followed the steps below:

Firstly, i created a virtual environment and activated it.

After that, i added it to the python path.

And then, i installed git and gcc such as below.

`yes | sudo yum install git`

`sudo yum install gcc72 gcc72-c++`

Lastly, i clonned the xgboost from source.

When i run the `make` command, i'm getting an error such as below:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/parallel/tags.h:36:10: fatal error: omp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <omp.h>
          ^~~~~~~
```

I'm using python3.6 and my gcc version is `g++ (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)`

How can i fix this?

Comment: The `omp.h` header should come with your GCC compiler installation. Can you locate it on your machine? `find /usr -name omp.h`. Perhaps, instead of cherry-picking these `gcc` packages to install, you might try installing *all* of the development tools `sudo yum group install "Development Tools"`

Comment: yes, i find it by using the command that you mentioned. it's in ```/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/include/omp.h```

Comment: It looks like this `omp.h` file you found is part of a GCC 4.8.5 installation, not GCC 7.2. Is there already a GCC installed? Perhaps, not all requisite files installed using `yum install gcc72 gcc72-c++` or this install is masking an older GCC version and confusing your build.

Comment: Yes, there is a default gcc 4.8.5 but i need a higher version. How can i upgrade the exist one?